# Counting Related Foreign Keys Goes Wrong

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables : company, devices, items .

items table content are linked to devices with foreign key, and devices are linked to company with another foreign key .

What i want :

Count the linked items to a selected record in devices table .

The following query gets the devices list :

```
SELECT devices.device_id,devices.device_name
FROM devices,company
WHERE devices.for_id = (company.company_name='Sony') 
ORDER BY devices.device_name ASC
```

Result :

```
id | device
0  | Device 1 
1  | Device 2
```

The following query gets the count correctly :

```
SELECT items.rom_name , COUNT(items.rom_name) AS 'count'
FROM items
WHERE items.device_for_id = 1
```

Result :

```
device | count
Device 1 | 2
Device 2 | 7
```

It's ok until now, i want to merge them together because i want to get it as a json response, So i've tried the following :

```
SELECT devices.device_name,devices.device_id,count(items.device_for_id) 
AS 'roms_count'
SFROM devices,company,items 
SWHERE devices.for_id=(company.company_name='".$_GET['company_name']."') 
SORDER BY devices.device_name ASC
```

Result :

```
Device | roms_count
Device 1 | 15
```

Here's my problem, the roms count isn't correct and it's getting the sum of all records, Plus it's showing only one device .

**device_for_id** in items is a foreign key .

What's the correct query for this ?

Update :

Company(company_id , company_name )

devices(device_id , device_name , for_id(foreign) )

items(device_for_id (foreign) , rom_id , rom_name )

Comment: devices.for_id is FK for company?

Comment: every item is linked to a device, every device is linked to a company, for example Windows 7 (item) is linked to Asus T100(device), which is linked to Asus(company) .

Comment: No, device_for_id in items is a foreign key to devices, the "for_id" in devices is the foreign key to company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT devices.device_name,devices.device_id,count(items.device_for_id) AS 'roms_count'
FROM devices 
LEFT JOIN company ON company.company_id=devices.for_id
LEFT JOIN items ON devices.device_id=items.device_for_id
WHERE company.company_name='Sony' 
GROUP BY devices.device_name,devices.device_id
ORDER BY devices.device_name ASC
```

Comment: The "roms_count" for all devices is the same now.

Comment: You have to specify which column you join devices, company and items. Show me fields of your table if you want more specific answer.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, you want the database tables structure right ? *English isn't my native.

Comment: Yes please, you don't have to give me details. You can just say, for example, devices(id, name, model), company(id, device_for_id, name), etc

Comment: Please check the Updated OP .

Comment: Updated answer, please try that

Comment: It's showing only one device, my guess because the other are null ? only one device got linked items, the other don't have any.

Comment: If you want to see 0, use LEFT JOIN. Updated answer.